# Vertices overlap with vertex labels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

How to prevent a behavior on a picture below? Why vertices overlap with vertex labels?

```
 n = 20;
 SeedRandom[1]
 Show@Graph[
 RandomGraph[{n, 5 n}],
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[n] -> Hash /@ Range[n]],
 VertexSize -> 0.5,
 GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding",
 ImageSize -> 700
 ]
```

[image: minimal example]

I drawing graphs of friends and it's connections from vk social network and often vertices overlap vertex labels. Very hard to read something on the right side of image:

[image: ego-net example]

Any ideas? It look like VertexRenderingFunction can not help in it case.

```
{$VersionNumber,$System}
(* {10.3, "Linux x86 (64-bit)"} *)
```

Comment: This is my first question, I worry a little bit

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround for this problem is to render the vertex labels separately.

```
n = 20;
SeedRandom[1]
g = Graph[
   RandomGraph[{n, 5 n}, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"],
   VertexSize -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 700];

Show[
 g,
 MapThread[Graphics@Text[#1, #2 + {0.4, 0.1}] &, 
   {Hash /@ Range[n], GraphEmbedding[g, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for late response, it works well! Thank you!